# Change order of modulo operation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given integer $p$ and $q$, where $gcd(p,q)=1$

and integer $r$ with realation:
$$ (x\; \text{mod}\,p)\;\text{mod}\,q=r $$
How to find the solutions of $s$, which satisfy the relation below ?
$$ (x\; \text{mod}\,q)\;\text{mod}\,p=s $$

This problem arise from the digital signature algortihm. If someone make a mistake on modulo order when calculate  $r\equiv (\alpha^{K_E}  \text{mod}\,p)\;\text{mod}\, q\ $, I want to know what is the effect on the result. 
I can find form the equations above,
I can get
$$ x= p\times a+q\times b+r$$ and
$$ x= p\times a'+q \times b'+s $$
the two equation give me
$$-r-s=p \times (a-a')+q\times(b-b') $$
It is a Diophantine equation with solution, but I stuck when to determine the range of the solution. For the same $x$ how to find the possible values of $s$?
Thanks to amWhy for reminding me to add the details.

Comment: If you are given $x$ then $s$ is specified (and you don't need to be given $r$). If you are only given $r$ then it is not.

Comment: Thanks for correction, only r is given. I know $s$ is not uniquely determined, but I want to make a systemic way to find multiple $s$.

Comment: That's what I figured.  But $r$ does not suffice.  To take a random example, let $p=5, q=8, r=2$.  Then $x=2$ gives the correct $r$ and yields $s=2$.  But $x=17$ also gives the correct $r$ and it yields $s=1$.

Comment: I believe you can get any value for $s$.  Take my example, with $p=5,q=8,r=2$.  Then let $x\in \{2,7,12,17,22,27,32,37\}$  It is easy to see that we get $s\in \{2,7,4,1,6,3,0,5\}$ which is every possible $s$.

Comment: @lulu I feel sorry to not make my question more clear. The question is about how for the same x, what is the realtion between r and s?

Comment: $x$ is not determined by $r$ so it makes no sense to talk about "the same $x$".  My example shows (I think) that for a specific $p,q,r$ we can get all possible $s$.

Comment: @lulu I got it, I will try to prove that we can get any value with these equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use $\%$ for the mod operator, and reserve mod for finite fields.

Suppose that $p<q$, $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and that we have $(x\%p)\%q=r$.

Obviously $x\%p<p<q$, so then $x\%p=r$.

So $x=r+b*p$ satisfies the requirements for any value of $b$ we like.

From $\gcd(p,q)=1$ we know that there are positive $m,n$ such that $mp-nq=1$. Let's choose our value of $b$ to be a multiple of $m$, i.e. $b=km$ where we are still free to choose $k$.

Now we have:
$x\%q = (r+bp)\%q = (r+kmp)\%q = (r+k(1+nq)))\%q = (r+k+knq)\%q = (r+k)\%q$

As we are free to choose $k$, we can make $x\%q$ become any value we like (between $0$ and $q-1$). Therefore $x\%q\%p$ can also take on any value we like (between $0$ and $p-1<q-1$).

In other words, I have shown that for any pair of values $r,s$ we can find a value of $x$ that works.